# Node.js Real-Time Stuff with DNode/shoe and all about load balancing

Tags: node.js, real-time, rpc, dnode

I have built a little system that uses dnode, shoe and browserify on the client, and NodeJS and dnode/shoe on the server end. I'm wondering if it is a good idea to use dnode (RPC) as the sole protocol for a real-time web application.

Let's look at the benefits of DNode or any other RPC interface. I like being able to call functions remotely (RPC). It definitely beats Ajax because you get a consistent interface for communicating from the client to the server and server to the client. I'm also betting that you get a small measure of performance over Ajax because of the HTTP overhead involved with Ajax.

However, using RPC, you have to deal with load balancing and the client connections on the server. But this goes with any websocket implementation. But, with other websocket implementation, you have a more traditional event based system, where the client listens to events from the server and responds to those events. I tried replicating this sort of interface using EventEmitters, but it's awful, and I keep getting warnings about too many handlers. Ugh!

I'm looking to achieve a lightweight, clean, interface that I can use to develop my application with. One that feels robust and is able to scale to many clients. It needs to feel solid.

I'm not really sure what my question is in writing this post. I'm tasked to update this codebase I wrote so that connections aren't lost, and it's overall more robust. I guess I'm just desperate for advice or consulting with my application. Is there someone so willing as to go face-to-face with me on discussing this topic (RPC and real-time web applications)?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating some of the same topics as it seemed to me than some of the RPC libs were very cool, but not altogether practical for large scale apps. I actually started with NowJS, realized it was a dead project, moved to DNode/Shoe/Browserify, and finally have moved on to [SocketStream](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream) in an attempt to offload some of the dirty work to a project that has a unified goal.  I really didn't want rewrite what others had already done on this subject and socketstream makes that easy. To get back to your question, as you can see on their page, SocketStream uses sticky sessions. This is a big assumption but one that probably can't be worked around at the moment without further developments.  The reason I mention it is that they talk about some of the things they are working on as far as scaling goes. Might we worth a read or reaching out to the developer to see if you could talk things over with him. Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic! This was a great reply! I just got done watching Barne's talk on SocketStream and it got me interested in the framework. I need to look at how it works more. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could point you in that direction. Also take a look here for an interesting article on how to scale NodeJS on the backend using RabbitMQ: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/01/31/scaling-real-time-apps-on-cloud-foundry-using-node-js-and-rabbitmq/